# using parameters in default formula for another parameter in Pentaho report Designer

Tags: pentaho

I have two parameters defined in a Pentaho Report, both of them are dates, end date is something the user picks for eg. 2012-07-09 (July 9th 2012). The other parameter(start date) is hidden and is supposed to be the end date-6 so that would be July 3rd 2012. Is there any way I can pass the end date to the start date parameter and use it in the Default Formula value.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes. Define the end date first, and then in the default value for the start date, you can refer to [enddate] in your formula where you subtract 6.

The key thing is to define the endDate first, before the hidden start date.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried this and it doesnt work. I am actually passing these parameters to a sub-report which has charts to get a Sales trend from start Date to end Date. I have imported the parameters in the sub-report as well. I am not sure why this is not working.

Comment: check whether your parameters are correctly set or not by displaying them in the parent report - get the params right, before you worry about the subreport.  This does work - I use hidden parms from time to time.

Comment: Hi Codek, the value of start date is always July 4th not matter what I choose for the end date. Looks like it is always taking the current date-7 and not what the user chooses in the date parameter. I have defined end date before the start date and chosen it in the formula as well.

Comment: Ah ;Make sure you use the "post processin formula" not the default value formula..

Comment: Had this problem before, the post-process formula worked for me

Comment: It's not a problem; It's how it works. Default value formula is executed BEFORE the prompt, and post process after.